# In Rust, what's the idiomatic way to split a &str into an iterator of &strs of one character each?

Tags: string, generics, rust, iterator, traits

If I want to take a `&str` like `"aeiou"` and turn it into an iterator roughly equivalent to `["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].iter()`, what's the most idiomatic way to do it?

I've tried doing `"aeiou".split("")` which seemed idiomatic to me, but I got empty `&str`s at the beginning and end.

I've tried doing `"aeiou".chars()` but it got pretty ugly and unwieldy from there trying to turn the `char`s into `&str`s.

For the time being, I just typed out `["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].iter()`, but there's got to be an easier, more idiomatic way.

For context, I'm eventually going to be looping over each value and passing it into something like `string.matches(vowel).count()`.

Here's my overall code.  Maybe I went astray somewhere else.

```
fn string_list_item_count<'a, I>(string: &str, list: I) -> usize
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>,
{
    let mut num_instances = 0;

    for item in list {
        num_instances += string.matches(item).count();
    }

    num_instances
}

// snip

string_list_item_count(string, vec!["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"])

// snip
```

If I could make `string_list_item_count` accept the `std::str::pattern::Pattern` trait inside the iterator, I think that would make this function accept iterators of `&str` and `char`, but the `Pattern` trait is a nightly unstable API and I'm trying to avoid using those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to a list of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47829646/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-list-of-chars)

Comment: No, I'm looking to basically do the opposite. Turn an iterator of chars into an iterator of &strs.

Comment: How do you define character in the context of your question? ASCII character? Unicode codepoint? Grapheme cluster? ...?

Comment: That's a good point. And it's why I wish Pattern was stable so I didn't have to specify exactly one type. I wish I could use anything that .matches accepts. It's kind of odd to me that .matches is stable but its underlying trait is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`split_terminator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_terminator) instead of `split` to skip the empty string at the end of the iterator. Additionally, if you [`skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) the first element of the iterator, you get the result you want:

```
let iterator = "aeiou".split_terminator("").skip(1);
println!("{:?}", iterator.collect::<Vec<_>>());
```

Output:

```
["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
```

Comment: Huh. That's interesting. It still feels a bit bad just because it's more characters than just typing out the vec. 

Comment: Yes. But it does scale better for longer strings

Answer (score 2):

I would use `str::split` with an empty string and then remove any empty strings using `Iterator::filter`:

```
fn string_chars(s: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = &str> {
    s.split("").filter(|s| !s.is_empty())
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        string_chars("aeiou").collect::<Vec<_>>(),
        ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"],
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A closure can also serve as a [`Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html#implementors):

```
fn main() {
    let vowels = "aeiou";
    let s = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    let count = string_item_count(s, vowels);
    dbg!(count);
}

fn string_item_count(string: &str, pat: &str) -> usize {
    let pred = |c| pat.contains(c);
    string.matches(pred).count()
}
```